# Magento 2 - Is it allowed to override styles-m.css / styles-l.css?

Tags: magento2, css, less

I read that these files are generated from .less files. So it is even allowed to override them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these are generated files. Created by the command `setup:static-content:deploy`. You are not supposed to change them.

You are supposed to create your own less files or extend existing ones.

Please read the docs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html

Comment: Do I have to run an external compiler if I use .less in magento 2?

Comment: It depends on the deploy-mode you are working in.

Comment: I think I will stay at css, its much easier.

Comment: But it's extremely vurnerable for errors! You should not do this

Comment: I never came across any errors and I do this all the time. There is no good tutorial or documentation on how to use .less, all I found was not working. So I am forced to use .css until they will finally release a working walkthroug for beginners.